# Compute the surface of $M=\{(x,y,z):2z=x^2+y^2,z<2\}$

Tags: integration

> Compute the surface of $M=\{(x,y,z):2z=x^2+y^2,z<2\}$.

**EDIT**

I've deleted my previous attempts, because they were wrong (as noted in the comments). While I have accepted an answer, I've written down my own approach here below.

First we find a parametrization for our paraboloid. For $r\in(0,2),\theta\in(0,2\pi)$ we define
$$
\phi(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r^2/2).
$$
The image of $\phi$ yields $M$, except for a set of measure zero, so that is ok. We want to compute the following integral:
$$
\int_MdV=\int_{(0,2)\times(0,2\pi)}V(D\phi).
$$
So we need the volume element $V(D\phi)=\sqrt{\operatorname{det}(D\phi^TD\phi)}$. We have
$$
D\phi(r,\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&-r\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\\
r&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which yields
$$
D\phi^TD\phi=\begin{pmatrix}1+r^2&0\\0&r^2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So we have $V(D\phi)=\sqrt{r^2(1+r^2)}=r\sqrt{1+r^2}$ (we can drop the absolute value for $r$, because $r>0$). At last, we compute the 2-dimensional volume:
$$
\int_{r=0}^2\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}r\sqrt{1+r^2}\,d\theta dr=2\pi\int_{r=0}^2r\sqrt{1+r^2}\,dr=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}(5\sqrt 5-1).$$

Comment: The set up is not for the surface but for the volume.

Comment: O right, thanks! That should make things easier - I will adjust it.

Comment: You shouldn't even need an integral to compute the surface area of a right circular cone...geometry suffices.

Comment: @rogerl The point is to practise computing integrals in 3D.

Comment: Then note that this is a surface of revolution, so the required integral takes a pretty simple form.

Comment: @ShaVuklia But you need to calculate the surface or the volume?

Comment: @gimusi I need to find the surface. I'm hesitating whether I should be working in cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @ShaVuklia I think that in this case cylindrical coordinates would be convenient

Comment: @gimusi O right! And then I apply the change-of-variable theorem, and I should get there. I will try to work it out, thanks!

Comment: @ShaVuklia Note that the present set up you made is for the volume computation and not for the surface. Take a look here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx

Comment: @gimusi Could you check if my approach with cylindrical coordinates is right?

Comment: @ShaVuklia It seems uncorrect, I'll add an answer with the set up.

Comment: what do you mean by "compute the surface" of "find the surface"? Do you need to compute the volume it encloses, or compute the surface area, or plot it? As is, your question is unclear.

Comment: I am supposed to compute the surface area. I think my latest approach is correct. @Mirko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In polar coordinates we have

- $0\le z \le 2$
- $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$
- $r(z)=\sqrt{2z}$

also note that

- $\frac{dr}{dz}=\frac1{\sqrt{2z}}\implies dr=\frac1{\sqrt{2z}}dz\implies ds=\sqrt{dz^2+dr^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+2z}{2z}}dz$

then

$$S=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^2 r(z)\,ds=2\pi\int_0^2 \sqrt{2z}\sqrt{\frac{1+2z}{2z}}\,dz=2\pi\int_0^2 \sqrt{1+2z}\,dz$$

As an alternative by your parametrization the surface integral is

$$S=\iint_M|\vec \phi_r\times \vec \phi_\theta|\,dr\,d\theta$$

with

- $\vec \phi_r=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta,r)$
- $\vec \phi_\theta=(-r\sin \theta,r\cos \theta,0)$

and then

- $\vec \phi_r\times \vec \phi_\theta=(-r^2\cos \theta,-r^2\sin \theta,r)$
- $|\vec \phi_r\times \vec \phi_\theta|=\sqrt{r^4+r^2}=r\sqrt{1+r^2}$

and finally

$$S=\iint_Mr\sqrt{1+r^2}\,dr\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^2 r\sqrt{1+r^2}\,dr=2\pi\left[\frac13(1+r^2)^\frac32\right]_0^2=\frac{2\pi}3\left(5\sqrt 5 -1\right)$$

Comment: I am not familiar with you're doing (though I can follow it sort of). I edited my answer again, and while I do think I'm following the right approach, I seem to have made some calculation errors, because the value is too big

Comment: Ok I will check it!

Comment: Thanks! I have seen your second method mentioned in my book, and it seems we do the same thing (same limits of integration), but we both have different volume elements. I wonder what went wrong with my volume element. Strange..

Comment: O, I'm so stupid! I interchanged the last to entries of my $D\phi$ matrix. Now I have the same volume element. Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @ShaVuklia Ah ok, well done! You are welcome, Bye!

Answer (score 0):

Noe That  the surface area of $$M=\{(x,y,z):2z=x^2+y^2,z<2\}$$ is the  surface of revolution  generated by rotating the region  in $xz$ plane bounded by $z=\frac {1}{2} x^2$, 
 $x=0$ , and $z=2$ about the $z-axis.$

Thus  the surface area is $$ S=\int _0^2 2\pi x ds = \int _0^2 2\pi x \sqrt {1+z'^2}dx=\\  \int _0^2 2\pi x \sqrt {1+x^2}dx =\\ \frac {2\pi}{3}(5\sqrt 5 -1)  $$